# How is this concise partial derivative statement true?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

> If $xe^z=y^2z $ then $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{e^z}{y^2-xe^z}$$

This question has, honestly, stumped me.

Comment: Take the implicit derivative of both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiate both sides implicitly to get
$$
\frac{\partial \left[xe^z\right]}{\partial x} = e^z + xe^z z'
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial \left[y^2 z\right]}{\partial x} = y^2z'
$$
where $z' = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$, assuming $y$ is constant wrt $x$.

Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be rewritten as,

$$z = \frac{xe^z}{y^2}$$

Differentiating partially w.r.t $x$ and applying chain rule,

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{1}{y^2}\left(e^z+xe^z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right) \implies \frac{\partial z }{\partial x}(y^2-xe^z) = e^z \implies\color{blue}{\frac{\partial z }{ \partial x} = \frac{e^z}{y^2 - xe^z}}$$